# How do you create a SQLite3 Report

Tags: sqlite

I am creating a SQLite3 database and would like to know if it possible to create a report view similar to Microsoft Access? If this is possible, could someone answer with some resources I could review to learn how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLLite does not have reports. It's just a database engine. Though many people use the term "database" colloquially to cover a user interface + reports for accessing data, that is not what is generally meant by technical folks. Typically databases are just a means for storing and retrieving data in a more raw format, and user interfaces and report engines are in a separate layer of software.

There are many reporting engines out there, and Stack Overflow isn't a forum that specializes in software recommendations, but if you do a search specifically for reporting engines that can connect to SQLLite, you may find something you're looking for.